# ¿Cómo puedo detectar 2 espacios seguidos (o más) con expresiones regulares con javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, formularios

Estoy intentando buscar una forma de escribir  en un formulario (sea un input, un textarea o cualquier otro tipo de campo que permita  escritura,  como un iframe editable) y que me cambie los dos espacios  que escribe de vez en cuando mi teclado por un espacio solo. Bueno, además de que sólo pueda añadir espacios entre palabras, no al principio o al final del string. Y si me podéis ayudar a saber cómo poder permitir letras con tildes en español  (á, é, í... Á, É, Í...)

En teoría para controlar lo de los espacios es con `\s` pero tengo entendido que eso es para cualquier espacio, incluido tab, enter,  etc...

Yo sólo lo quiero para espacio de la  barra de espacio. Que me funciona fatal este teclado y de  vez en cuando hace como si le diese 2 veces a la barra de espacio...

Y quiero que sólo me funcione con los espacios entre palabras para que, si en un textarea incluyo más de un  enter en blanco no me lo deje en uno solo.  Por eso no creo que mi caso  sea usar `\s`...

Y estaba buscando la forma de  que el javascript según le doy a la barra de espacio, si se insertan solos 2 espacios, me borre uno de ellos.

Creo que se me entiende bien.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Actualmente no tengo ninguno porque el que  tenía  me decía  que no  era una expresión. Y cuando  no me salía eso, me decía que test no  era un método  o  una función. Si no recuerdo mal. Creo que lo que había  intentado usar  era algo así: `/\S\w[\s]*(.*?)[\s]*$/`. También lo he intentado con  algo  así: `/^\w*[\s{1,}]/`.  En principio intentando ver  si era capaz de  hacer que detecte cuando  hay más de 1  espacio. también he intentado sustituyendo `\s`  por `\x020`, pues leí no sé dónde que es el  caracter del  espacio. Lo cierto es que  es  tan  complejo que me he hecho un lío.

Comment: /\s\s+/g     https://regexr.com/

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres es quitarle a un texto los espacios de más que haya, te hice un ejemplo.

```js
let texto = 'Yo          soy tu padre    '.trim();

const expRegular = /(\s{2,})/g;

let remplazar = texto.replace(expRegular,' ');

console.log(remplazar)
```

Explicación expresión regular `/(\s{2,})/g`

- `\s{2,}` -> `\s` (espacio) , `{2,}` si hay minimo 2 espacios o mas seguidos.
- `/g` -> Global, para que sea en todo el texto.

Ejemplo completo en input:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

 <input type="text" name="NombreProducto" id="NombreProducto" value="" onkeypress="comprobarEspacios()" required>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function comprobarEspacios() {
   
   let input = document.getElementById('NombreProducto');

   let remplazar = input.value.replace(/(\s{2,})/g, ' ');

   input.value = remplazar;
  }
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas  gracias!

Comment: ¡Muchas  gracias! En principio sí que funciona, pero  al intentar pasarlo a  mi formulario, no lo logro. El  input es: `<input type="text" name="NombreProducto" id="NombreProducto" value="<?php echo $miProducto->getNombre() ?>" onkeypress="comprobarEspacios()" required>`

Comment: Y el script es: `<script type="text/javascript">
     function comprobarEspacios(){
      let nombre = document.getElementById('NombreProducto').value;
      alert(document.getElementById('NombreProducto').value);
      let texto = nombre.trim();
      const expRegular = /(\s{2,})/g;
      let remplazar = texto.replace(expRegular,' ');
      console.log(remplazar);
     }
    </script>`

Comment: Ni  me da error,  ni  funciona... como si no  hubiera  escrito ni una línea de script...

Comment: ¡Estupendo! Ahora, sí que me funciona...  sólo me  falta borrar el espacio del principio y el final...¡Muchas gracias! Por  cierto, que lo he  intentado  modificar de varias formas y no hay manera. Pero eso  ya  es cuestión de otra pregunta, supongo. La  parte principal, que era ésa y que me  traía  de cabeza, funciona perfecto.